# hyperledger composer V 0.12 deploy fails

Tags: node.js, sdk, hyperledger-composer

Working with Hyperledger Composer V0.12 invoking the deploy function using the following code, which returns a 'successful' result:

```
/**
 * Deploys a new BusinessNetworkDefinition to the Hyperledger Fabric. The connection must be connected for this method to succeed.
 * @param {express.req} req - the inbound request object from the client
 *  req.body.myArchive: _string - string name of object
 *  req.body.deployOptions: _object - string name of object
 * @param {express.res} res - the outbound response object for communicating back to client
 * @param {express.next} next - an express service to enable post processing prior to responding to the client
 * returns composerAdmin.connection - either an error or a connection object
 * @function
 */
exports.deploy = function(req, res, next) {

let newFile = path.join(path.dirname(require.main.filename),'network/dist',req.body.myArchive);
let archiveFile = fs.readFileSync(newFile);

let adminConnection = new composerAdmin.AdminConnection();

return BusinessNetworkDefinition.fromArchive(archiveFile)
    .then(function(archive) {
        adminConnection.connect(config.composer.connectionProfile, config.composer.adminID, config.composer.adminPW)
        .then(function(){
            adminConnection.deploy(archive)
                .then(function(){
                    console.log('business network '+req.body.myArchive+' deployed successful: ');
                    res.send({deploy: req.body.myArchive+' deploy succeeded'});
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    console.log('business network '+req.body.myArchive+' deploy failed: ',error);
                    res.send({deploy: error});
                    });
            });
        });
};
```

However when I go through the following process:

1. start docker images, deploy network using cli
2. ping
3. undeploy
4. ping
5. deploy
6. ping

I get the following results:

```
[2] at: 08:10:36.058 Url is: /composer/admin/ping
network ping successful:  { version: '0.12.0', participant: null }
[3] at: 08:11:05.503 Url is: /composer/admin/undeploy
zerotoblockchain-network network undeploy successful 
[4] at: 08:11:25.186 Url is: /composer/admin/ping
(node:18241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The business network has been undeployed)
[5] at: 08:11:34.393 Url is: /composer/admin/deploy
business network zerotoblockchain-network.bna deployed successful: 
[6] at: 08:11:44.211 Url is: /composer/admin/ping
(node:18241) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query chaincode. Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error: The business network has been undeployed)
```

This indicates that the composer deploy function is not actually deploying the network, even though I appear to receive a successful completion message from the deploy service. Help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you undeploy a business network, all it does is mark the business network as unreachable. It remains deployed and still running. The reason for this is that currently Hyperledger fabric provides no mechanism for shutting down instantiated chaincode. So all we can do is mark it as unusable.
The deploy API and command are the old way to get a business network up and running. The new way is the install/start combination. The reason that deploy reports successful is that it has to make decisions about errors reported back by both the install and start commands in order to continue to work in an expected manner in the Hyperledger Fabric way of doing things. So although it reports a success for deploying, it's really doing nothing because it is already deployed.

Comment: Thanks! install/start combination not documented anywhere in the nodejs SDK. Is this CLI only?

Comment: install and start are documented in the API reference.
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/module-composer-admin.AdminConnection.html#install__anchor
and
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/module-composer-admin.AdminConnection.html#start__anchor
At some point we hope to move our documentation over demonstrating this rather than deploy, but for the most part deploy still works they exist because install and start can require different credentials

Comment: Update. Am now working with the install and start commands rather than the deploy function. Still failing in that if I undeploy a network (now unusable, still installed) and I attempt to install that network again, it fails with the following message: ```Error: chaincode error (status: 500, message: Error installing chaincode code zerotoblockchain-network:0.12.0(chaincode /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/zerotoblockchain-network.0.12.0 exists))``` The 0.12.0 is the composer version # and this appears to require that I now rename my base network to do a reinstall.

Comment: Hyperledger fabric Version 1 provides no way to undeploy chaincode and terminate the chaincode containers. As a consequence of that all composer can do is mark the business network as unusable. But in essence that chaincode and container are still running. So if you want to deploy again you will need to change the name of the business network. However if you are looking to just update your business network with new content, then there is the composer network update command.